# Docusaurus MDX rendering

Tags: reactjs, markdown, documentation, docusaurus

I'm working with some DOCS with Docusaurus by Facebook.

I'm trying to rendere some MDX docs, like this:

```
---
id: colors
title: Colors
---

## Library

<pre style={{ background: "black" }}>zzz</pre>
```

Docusaurus treats the MD file as mere markdown, trying to render an HTML `<pre>zzz</pre>` with errors on styling.
Not trying to render JSX.

I Also tried to rename the file from `test.md` to `test.mdx` and It seems that Docusaurus won't find the file anymore.

Is there any setting I'm missing? It's like I've no MDX rendering at all.

My Package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "examples": "docusaurus-examples",
    "start": "docusaurus-start",
    "build": "docusaurus-build",
    "publish-gh-pages": "docusaurus-publish",
    "write-translations": "docusaurus-write-translations",
    "version": "docusaurus-version",
    "rename-version": "docusaurus-rename-version"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "docusaurus": "^1.14.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@docusaurus/mdx-loader": "^2.0.0-alpha.37",
    "@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs": "^2.0.0-alpha.37",
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you put the full MDX file here? Newlines matter in MDX and it might be the cause.

Comment: @YangshunTay it was not... problem is that V1 has no MDX

Comment: Yeah v1 uses remarkable, not MDX

Answer (score 1):

This should just work with Docusaurus, shouldn't need any additional packages, add the text color property to see the text as shown below:

```
<pre style={{ background: "black", color: "white" }}>zzz</pre>
```